# How to point my primary domain to sub folder

Tags: css, .htaccess, dns

i'm trying to point my primary domain to a sub folder in my /publichtml

i found a way to do it using this [URL](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1114233)
. However there's something wrong because when i load my page, it's like the page is not styled with css

my URL is stormreadersdev.com

the subdomain i'm trying to point is [store.stormreadersdev.com](http://store.stormreadersdev.com)

Please advice, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the file path to your CSS file. For example, if you originally referenced your CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" tyoe="text/css" href="file.css>
```

Now you may need to reference your CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../file.css">
```

This article may help: https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/.